# Get A List of Foreign Key Constraints for EF code first entity

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to determine the foreign keys on an entity in an EF code first scenario,

the code I have so far tells me the tables to which the foreign keys relate (or rather the navigation properties), but I need the properties that represent the relationship at either end (a simple string would do):

```
public void DetermineForiegnKeys<T>()
{
    entitySet = ((IObjectContextAdapter)dbbuilder.s200).ObjectContext.CreateObjectSet<T>().EntitySet;
    var nps = entitySet.Value.ElementType.NavigationProperties;

    foreach (var np in nps)
    {
        var otherTableType = ((RefType)np.FromEndMember.TypeUsage.EdmType).ElementType;
        var otherIsFrom = true;
        if (otherTableType.Name.Equals(typeof(T).Name))
        {
            otherTableType = ((RefType)np.ToEndMember.TypeUsage.EdmType).ElementType;
            otherIsFrom = false;
        }
        //how do I get the property names on this entity (T) and the other??
        // just the IDs, not the virtual properties...
     }
}
```

Comment: I have field on the other table if I assume it is the PK of that table:  `var ForeignField = otherTableType.KeyMembers.Single().Name`

Comment: This approach cannot however give the field on the local table (even by looking at the FK constraint from the other end) as there is no guarantee that the field is the PK on the local table(and in general it wont be), I'm stuck as to where to go from here...

Answer (score 3):

I know it may be an old question, but I will leave a solution here just in case. Once you have obtained a `NavigationProperty` you can use `GetDependentProperties` to get a list of the foreign keys. The tricky part is that the method return keys only for CSpace types. So, we have to convert our proxy type to CSpace type.

```
public static string[] GetForeignKeys(DbContext context, Type type)
{
    StructuralType edmType = GetCSpaceType(context, type);

    var members = edmType
                        .MetadataProperties
                        .Where(mp => mp.Name == "Members")
                        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (members != null && members.Value != null)
    {
        List<NavigationProperty> navProps = ((ICollection<EdmMember>)members.Value)
                                            .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.NavigationProperty)
                                            .Cast<NavigationProperty>()
                                            .Where(p =>
                                                ((AssociationType)p.RelationshipType).IsForeignKey
                                            )
                                            .ToList();
        List<EdmProperty> foreignKeys = navProps
                                        .SelectMany(p => p.GetDependentProperties())
                                        .ToList();
        return foreignKeys.Select(p => p.Name).ToArray();
    }
    return null;
}

private static StructuralType GetCSpaceType(DbContext context, Type type)
{
    MetadataWorkspace workspace = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext.MetadataWorkspace;
    EdmType ospaceType = workspace.GetType(type.Name, type.Namespace, DataSpace.OSpace);
    return workspace.GetEdmSpaceType((StructuralType)ospaceType);
}
```

**UPDATE:** to be more specific and get a foreign key for related entity of a specific type you can do the following:

```
public static PropertyInfo GetForeignKey(DbContext context, Type type, Type related)
{
    StructuralType edmType = GetCSpaceType(context, type);
    StructuralType parentEdmType = GetCSpaceType(context, related);

    var members = edmType
                        .MetadataProperties
                        .Where(mp => mp.Name == "Members")
                        .FirstOrDefault();
    if (members != null && members.Value != null)
    {
        List<NavigationProperty> navProps = ((ICollection<EdmMember>)members.Value)
                                            .Where(m => m.BuiltInTypeKind == BuiltInTypeKind.NavigationProperty)
                                            .Cast<NavigationProperty>()
                                            .Where(p =>
                                                ((AssociationType)p.RelationshipType).IsForeignKey
                                            )
                                            .ToList();

        NavigationProperty navProp = navProps
                                        .FirstOrDefault(p => ((RefType)p.ToEndMember.TypeUsage.EdmType).ElementType.FullName == parentEdmType.FullName);

        if (navProp != null)
        {
            var dependent = navProp.GetDependentProperties().ToList();
            if (dependent.Count > 0)
            {
                return type.GetProperty(dependent[0].Name);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that gives me the name of the foreign keys, however it does not provide the Type for the other table or the field that is linked on that other table.

Comment: @MikeW so you wish to filter navProperties by type T and get the foreign key which points to entity of type T?